# OnTouchListener not working inside Activity

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

so I had some problems with the onTouch method, it didnt do anything, at first i thought something wrogn with the code but then i did this, and it still doesnt work when i touch the screen. Anyone knows what is the problem? Thnx.

{
    private FartPianoView fpv;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    fpv = new FartPianoView(this);
    setContentView(fpv);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            finish();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **override** the

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent e)
```

method of the `Activity` class, **not the method you are overriding** (`onTouch(...)` of the `OnTouchListener`). Then it should work. Example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    // do your stuff...

    return false;
}
```

This means you are recognizing touch events on the `Activity`, not on the `View`. If you want to explicitly detect touches on the `View` via `OnTouchListener`, you need to set the `OnTouchListener` for your `View`.

In your case:

```
fpv = new FartPianoView(this);
fpv.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: What about your FartPianoView? Does it intercept touch gestures?

Comment: Another question, for some reason when im using methods from the fpv it doesnt work. Any idea why?